# What happens when you compare uninitialized heap memory with nullptr in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, heap-memory, function-pointers

As the question states, I'm trying to understand a condition that is happening in my current application.
I'm attempting to load function pointers from a DLL. The DLL is loaded using `LoadLibraryA` and this is successful. This DLL has multiple methods that I need access to, and the `typedef` of those method pointers are also available, however, they are not initialized to nullptr.
During init, I do a comparison of the method pointers with null pointers to check if they are already loaded. I saw that all of these method pointers have the value `0xbaadf00d`, and wikipedia suggests `("bad food") is used by Microsoft's LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED) to indicate uninitialised allocated heap memory when the debug heap is used.`
This is also what [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d74a06b9-a780-4ae9-966b-21e7cc532bde/access-violation-reading-location-0xbaadf00d?forum=vclanguage) says.
So what happens when this comparison of uninitialized method pointers to null pointer is done? It would be great if someone could help me understand this.

Comment: _So what happens when this comparison of uninitialized method pointers to null pointer is done?_ If you check a non-null pointer whether it's null the result will be false. (Actually not that surprising.) Please, note that MSCV in debug mode will fill the memory with test patterns (to support better debugging) but in release mode you may have arbitrary values. This can result in very hard to find errors as you have somehow a reproducible behavior in debug which you lose in release. Hence, you will have sporadic errors in release which are not reproducible in debug - a bad trap.

Comment: Any use of an uninitialised value is undefined behaviour